# Question marks when outputting data from database

Tags: mysql, character-encoding

I have set charset to utf-8 everwhere in my database, in all tables and columns. It still won't display properly and question marks appears where non-latin letters appear. Is there something else that needs to be done or have I just forgotten something?

Comment: Is the php file in utf-8 also ?

Comment: @CappY Ye I save it as utf-8 without BOM the first thing I do when I create a new file.


edit:What the f*ck. Now when I remove the `<meta charset="utf-8" />`  tag in the `<head>` the output from the database is displayed correctly while everything else that is static has question marks.

Comment: I just noticed that my function files that does the MySQL queries and returns content from the database doesn't want to be converted to UTF-8. If I close the file and then open it again it says it's in ANSI (I use Notepad++).

Comment: You can try just for test when you get record from DB, `var_dump(mb_detect_encoding('string'))` to see encoding.

Comment: @CappY It says `string(5) "UTF-8"`. I think the problem is that some files won't convert to UTF-8 properly.

Answer (score 1):

Set charset to `UTF-8` in your PDO connection like this:

```
"mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydbname;charset=utf8,username,password"
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I fixed it by changing the format on all my PHP-files to ANSI in Notepad++ and then adding `<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">` into my header. Doesn't feel like a legit fix though.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
mysql_set_charset('utf8',$mysql);
```